# puting a time limit on something with flutter

Tags: flutter, date, dart, time, duration

I have an flutter app with many "tasks". Users can earn XP and level up by completing tasks.
I want some tasks only to be able to be do once a day or once a week. I can create a "Duration" when task is complete but after that I am lost.

for example I have a variable like this.

```
Duration oneDay = Duration(hours: 24);
```

How can I disable -so the user can see but can't click- a completed task for one day?